# objectListView Getting items Text multiple colums

Tags: c#, visual-studio, objectlistview

Hi can some one help I have had little sucess.I want to get the text from an objectListView control. The item would need to contain all the text in the cells I belive they call the text from an objectListContol.
Any help greatly appreated.

It would also be handy to know how to add reliably text into containers/cells in the objectListview.Can you set only certain colums to be eddited?

Comment: Its not clear to me what you are asking in the first part of you question. You just configure the OLV to access your data objects properties through the AspectName or you use AspectGetter and AspectPutter delegates. Regarding editing: You can enable/disable editing for each individual OlvColumn.

Comment: I dont know 1 how to add the list of items? 2.how to get the text values of the selected row? Can you give an example how to, "you just configure the OLV to accsess your data objects" I have a listview of items which I was hoping to add to objectview and have them, be selected edited.

Comment: You should really read and study the official documentation, its pretty comprehensive. Especially the [Getting started](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/gettingStarted.html) section is useful. And take a look at the demo projects, there are lots of code examples in there. You essentially ask how to use the OLV, this is way too unspecific.